# How can I use a local image using vscode-devcontainer

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-devcontainer

Currently I am running the docker container using `docker run` command, I found vscode container and seems intresting. I created a workspace and a `devcontainer.json`.

**devcontainer.json**

```
{
    "name": "dev",
    "image": "demo:focal",
    "containerUser": "root",
    "runArgs": [
        "--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE",
        "--security-opt",
        "seccomp=unconfined",
        "--security-opt",
        "apparmor=unconfined",
        "--network=host",
        "--privileged"
    ]
}
```

I already built the dockerimage and I dont want to rebuilt again.So I am using the docker image name in the json file.But while opening the container I am getting the below errors:

```
=> ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/demo:f  1.4s
=> [context dev_containers_feature_content_source] load .dockerignore     0.0s
=> => transferring dev_containers_feature_content_source: 2B              0.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/demo:focal:
------
[2022-10-27T06:53:02.045Z] Dockerfile.extended:8
--------------------
   6 |     
   7 |     
   8 | >>> FROM $_DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE AS dev_containers_target_stage
   9 |     
  10 |     USER root
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
[2022-10-27T06:53:02.053Z] Stop (2681 ms): Run: docker buildx build --load --build-context dev_containers_feature_content_source=/tmp/devcontainercli-user_s/container-features/0.20.0-1666853579352
[2022-10-27T06:53:02.053Z] Error: Command failed: docker buildx build --load --build-context dev_containers_feature_content_source=/tmp/devcontainercli-user_s/container-features/0.20.0-1666853579352]
```

I can able to run the same image using the `docker run` command but not able to find what is the issue with the dev container?

Comment: Try the same command `docker buildx build --load --build-context dev_containers_feature_content_source=/tmp/devcontainercli-user_s/container-features/0.20.0-1666853579352` in the error message to see a detailed error from the terminal

Comment: Have you tried specifying only image name, but with the version?
Same as in the output of the `docker ps` command.

Also what works great for me is *Attach to running container* option. 
Can also be extended with the settings, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/devcontainers/attach-container

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue before.

To solve this problem, you should use `F1 > Dev Containers: Rebuild Container` rather than `F1 > Dev Containers: Rebuild Container Without Cache`.

Then it should be able to use a local image. Tested on my local and worked fine.